# What do the inputs of `hash_df` look like?

Tags: encryption, random-number-generator, implementation

I am making an implementation of `hash_df` (NIST documentation found in [SP800-90A.pdf](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-90A/SP800-90A.pdf) on page 67)

I found [*“Does hash_df use binary or an ASCII hexadecimal representation for numbers to be passed to the hash function?”*](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1415/) which explained a few things, but im still not completely sure that I have it right. I am having trouble with part 4.1 under Hash_df Process as seen below

```
temp = temp || Hash (counter || no_of_bits_to_return || input_string)
```

`Counter` is expected to be a 1 byte binary value
`no_of_bits_to_return` is a 4 byte big-endian binary value
`input_string` is the concatenation of entropy_input, nonce and personalization_string.

so as an example if **counter = 2**, **no_of_bits_to_return = 16** and **input_string = "8581f93h"** the later part of the function would look like this: (|| is concatenation. The no_of_bits_to_return binary value in my example could be incorrect. I need to get more familiar with big-endian  I just put this one in a converter)

```
hash(00000010 || 16000000 || 0011100000110101001110000011000101100110 001110010011001101101000)
```

Is this correct as per the NIST SP 800-90A documentation? I can’t find the documentation to confirm my assumptions and I am afraid I am horribly wrong.

Comment: `no_of_bits_to_return` is bigendian, and so 16 would be encoded as (in binary) 00000000000000000000000000010000.  All 'bigendian' means is 'big end first', that is, the msbyte is the first one, and the lsbyte is the last one.